# Is the Union Version not a direct translation of KJV?

Tags: bible, bible-translation

The translation to Chinese by Union Version of Bible at [this website](https://www.o-bible.com/cgibin/ob.cgi?version=hgb&book=1ti&chapter=1) says:

> **提 摩 太 前 书 1 Timothy**
>
> 1:10      行 淫 和 亲 男 色 的 ， 抢 人 口 和 说 谎 话 的 ， 并 起 假 誓 的 ， 或 是 为 别 样 敌 正 道
> 的 事 设 立 的 。

The corresponding part in KJV at [this website](https://www.o-bible.com/cgibin/ob.cgi?version=kjv&book=1ti&chapter=1) says

> **1 Timothy**
>
> 1:10      For whoremongers, for them that defile themselves with mankind, for menstealers, for liars, for perjured persons, and if there be any other thing that is contrary to sound doctrine;

If I am correct, "whoremongers" isn't gender specific. Where did "亲 男 色 的" originate?
Is the Union Version not a direct translation of KJV?

Comment: I think you meant King James Version, another translation in the website you referenced.  The abbreviation is KJV, not KLV.  I edited your question accordingly.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple thanks.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question.  I suspect it was a simple typographical error on your part, the letter K being next to the letter L.  It was fun finding out that there is a Klingon version, although my laptop refused to allow me access to any link related to it.  I will go back to my answer and deal with your additional question.

Answer (score 2):

***Let’s deal with your comment that “whoremongers” isn’t gender specific.***  The word “whoremonger” is an English word that refers to a person who consults with whores.  That would suggest male persons.   The King James Version uses that expression

The New International Version says “adulterers and perverts, for slave traders and liars and perjurers”.

***The Klingon Language Version (KLV) is not a Bible and is based on an artificial language.***

***You ask if the Union Version not a direct translation of KLV.*** Since I can neither read Chinese nor Klingon I am unable to answer your main question, although I found this information of the Chinese Union Version:

> ***The Chinese Union Version (CUV)*** is the predominant translation of the Bible into Chinese used by Chinese Protestants, first published in 1919.  A revision for the CUV, the Revised Chinese Union Version (RCUV) was completed for the New Testament in 2006, and for the entire Bible in 2010.  The CUV was translated by a panel with members from many different Protestant denominations, using the English Revised Version as a basis and original-language manuscripts for crosschecking.
> (Source: [Wikipedia: Chinese Union Version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Union_Version#:%7E:text=The%20Chinese%20Union%20Version%20(CUV,text%20is%20now%20available%20online))

**Edit:** Now that we’ve ascertained it is the King James Bible you are comparing with the Chinese Union Version, I am still at a loss to say whether the CUV has translated 1 Timothy 1:10 from the KJV. The link I found says the CUV used the English Revised Version of the Bible as a basis for its translation.

However, the main point of your question now seems to be if the word “whoremonger” is singling out gays and is anti-LGBTQ.  That is an entirely different subject, although you should bear in mind that promiscuous women who have sex with men are usually thought of as whores.

God’s plan for humanity is that a man will leave his father and mother and be united to his wife, and they will become one flesh” (Genesis 2:24).  The purpose of such sexual union is to procreate.  The Bible promotes heterosexual relationships.  If you want to explore this topic, please ask a new question.

**Conclusion:** I agree with you that the KJV is not anti-LGBTQ, but I can't read the Chinese translation.

Comment: Thanks. My understand of "亲 男 色 的"  is that it singles out gays. Is that translation in Union Version anti-LGBTQ, while  there is no such implication in the translation in KLV ?

Comment: Sorry I meant KJV by "KLV".